# In UIPinchGestureRecognizer get number of fingures involed in triggering the gesture?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In UIPinchGestureRecognizer how get number of fingures involed in triggering the gesture?

Answer (score 3):

From UIPinchGestureRecognizer Class Reference:

> UIPinchGestureRecognizer is a concrete
>   subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that
>   looks for pinching gestures involving
>   two touches

**Two touches.**

**Update**

@omz said about `numberOfTouches` method, inherited from `UIGestureRecognizer`. In `UIPinchGesstureRecognizer` it always return 2 or 1 (when user finishing gesture and take one finger from the screen).

**Update 2**

This gesture always *triggering* by 2 fingers as said in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-numberOfTouches` method (declared in `UIGestureRecognizer`, which is the superclass).

Answer (score -2):

check out [these Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html)!

And I quote out of this:

> To handle multitouch events, you must
>   first create a subclass of a responder
>   class. This subclass could be any one
>   of the following:
>
> - A custom view (subclass of UIView)
> - A subclass of UIViewController or one of
>     its UIKit subclasses
> - A subclass of a UIKit view or control class, such as
>     UIImageView or UISlider
> - A subclass of
>     UIApplication or UIWindow (although
>     this would be rare)
> - A view controller
>     typically receives, via the responder
>     chain, touch events initially sent to
>     its view if that view does not
>     override the touch-handling methods.
>
> For instances of your subclass to
>   receive multitouch events, your
>   subclass must implement one or more of
>   the UIResponder methods for
>   touch-event handling, described below.
>   In addition, the view must be visible
>   (neither transparent or hidden) and
>   must have its userInteractionEnabled
>   property set to YES, which is the
>   default.
>
> The following sections describe the
>   touch-event handling methods, describe
>   approaches for handling common
>   gestures, show an example of a
>   responder object that handles a
>   complex sequence of multitouch events,
>   discuss event forwarding, and suggest
>   some techniques for event handling.
>
> The Event-Handling Methods During a
>   multitouch sequence, the application
>   dispatches a series of event messages
>   to the target responder. To receive
>   and handle these messages, the class
>   of a responder object must implement
>   at least one of the following methods
>   declared by UIResponder, and, in some
>   cases, all of these methods:
>
> - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
> - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
> - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
> - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
>
> The application sends these messages
>   when there are new or changed touches
>   for a given touch phase:
>
> - It sends the touchesBegan:withEvent:
>     message when one or more fingers touch
>     down on the screen.
> - It sends the
>     touchesMoved:withEvent: message when
>     one or more fingers move.
> - It sends the
>     touchesEnded:withEvent: message when
>     one or more fingers lift up from the
>     screen.
> - It sends the
>     touchesCancelled:withEvent: message
>     when the touch sequence is cancelled
>     by a system event, such as an incoming
>     phone call.
>
> Each of these methods is
>   associated with a touch phase; for
>   example, touchesBegan:withEvent: is
>   associated with UITouchPhaseBegan. You
>   can get the phase of any UITouch
>   object by evaluating its phase
>   property.
>
> Each message that invokes an
>   event-handling method passes in two
>   parameters. The first is a set of
>   UITouch objects that represent new or
>   changed touches for the given phase.
>   The second parameter is a UIEvent
>   object representing this particular
>   event. From the event object you can
>   get all touch objects for the event or
>   a subset of those touch objects
>   filtered for specific views or
>   windows. Some of these touch objects
>   represent touches that have not
>   changed since the previous event
>   message or that have changed but are
>   in different phases.